# Empty reponse for ajax call in CakePHP 2.1

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

On CakePHP 2.1, I have an ajax request that gets an empty response (checked with firebug) and also triggers the error callback.

From my .js I'm calling a php from outside of cake -same server- to provide some database records I need:

```
function updateDiv() {
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'http://myserver/phpGenesi/api.php',
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {   
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data)
        {   
            alert('error')
        } 
    });        
}
```

This is the PHP code on the server (it works well and is not CakePHP, simply PHP db data):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName where project_id = 101"); 
$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);      


if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)  
{  
$responses = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $responses[] = array(  
        'id' => $row['id'],  
        'name' => $row['name'],  
        'dir_description' => $row['dir_description'],
        'project_id' => $row['project_id'],
        'dir_notes' => $row['dir_notes'],
        'dir_dataname' => $row['dir_dataname']
    );  
}
echo '{"dirs": ' . json_encode($responses) . '}';
}
```

I get the results just fine when I access the same php from outside cake, for example:

```
http://myserver/phpGenesi/api.php
```

returns what i need:

```
{"dirs": [{"id":"240","name":"c","dir_description":"Carlos Test c","project_id":"101","dir_notes":"c","dir_dataname":"c"},{"id":"241","name":"d","dir_description":"Carlos Test d","project_id":"101","dir_notes":"d","dir_dataname":"d"}]}
```

Also works if called from any client document.

The problem is when I call it from inside my cake document. Firebug shows empty response and my ajax error function is triggered.

Any idea on what it's missing? How can I know what error is occurring that is triggering my error function?

Comment: What status code do you get back? Have you checked apache logs for any hints?

Comment: thx tigrang. I get status 200 OK. Checked the logs and found no apparent fault: <br>     192.168.100.10 - - [24/Sep/2012:12:56:31 -0700] "GET /phpGenesi/api.php HTTP/1.1" 200 317 "http://dev.opm.asc/projects/edit/101" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"<br\>    
192.168.100.10 - - [24/Sep/2012:15:43:40 -0700] "GET /phpGenesi/api.php HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "http://dev.opm.asc/projects/edit/101" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1" <br\>    :-(

Comment: Just found out that locally it works; that is, I have a cake installation in localhost, duplicated the scenario and it worked like charm. My local cake is out of the box so I wonder whether some configuration on my production cake is preventing ajax from working or whether it has to do with apache in my server.    d..m  :-)